# Check word if exist (the word itself not a substring) in a sentence/string using PHP

Tags: php

Sentence: "As I look at the photo the boy looks photogenic"
Find: 'photo'
Result occurence: 1 (do not include photogenic)

All I can see available online is to check if a substring exist on a string. So as for the example above. Do you have any example how to do this? Thanks

Code sample on how to execute the question.

Comment: You can use the explode() function on the entire string, which will give you an array of all words, and then just iterate over the array looking for the exact match.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion I will use `explode()` method from PHP. You can check it in [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) . As the usage I will do:

```php
<?php

$string = "As I look at the photo the boy looks photogenic";
$found = explode(" photo ", strtolower($string));
echo count($found);
```

I use `strtolower()` just in case there's another `photo` word in uppercase.